# How to use replace_regex with list of regular expressions?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to summarize & count some activities from the Dependencies table using Kusto Query Language, in Azure. The Name field is a bunch of URLs with various formats, the issue being they regularly have customer IDs in them and, therefore, don't count/summarize nicely. To work around it, I have a list of regex patterns that would filter out the IDs, but I'm wondering the best way to use that in a query.

for example, the table: (sorry, table markdown wasn't cooperating)

```
| Name                                            | Success |
| :-----------------------------------------------| :----- |
| api/path?id=0150403650                          | True   |
| api/path?id=0150403651                          | False  |
| another/path/0150403611/validate                | True   |
| another/path/0150403612/validate                | False  |
| more/paths/4863FDA918BB42959C88E06D72E04238/etc | True   |
| more/paths/4863FDA918BB42959C88E06D72E04238/etc | False  |
```

Desired results:

```
| Name                                            | Success | Count |
| :-----------------------------------------------| :-----  | :---- |
| api/path?id=id                                  | True    | 1234  |
| api/path?id=id                                  | False   | 1234  |
| another/path/id/validate                        | True    | 1234  |
| another/path/id/validate                        | False   | 1234  |
| more/paths/guid/etc                             | True    | 1234  |
| more/paths/guid/etc                             | False   | 1234  |
```

current query (works, but feels goofy chaining the replace_regex like this):

```
dependencies
| extend call = replace_regex(replace_regex(name, @"[\/]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}", "guid"), @"[\/]+[0-9]{10}", "id")
| summarize c = count(call) by call, success
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
let regs = dynamic([@"[\/]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}", @"[\/]+[0-9]{10}", @"[=]{1}[0-9]{10}"]);
dependencies
//| where name matches regex regs
| extend call = replace_regex(name, regs, "")
| summarize c = count(call) by call, success
```

Comment: You're using the term *guid* for something that is clearly not a guid. What is your real need here (the regex pattern should be matched accordingly)?

Comment: You need to put some effort to your data sample. **(1)** The required results should match the data sample. Don't just invent numbers (1234). **(2)** The required results should match the attempted code. **(2.1)** Your attempted code replaces all the search patterns with an empty string, not *id* & *guid*. **(2.2)** Be decisive about columns' names. what would it be, *Count* or *c*?  **(4)** Your code does an aggregation but with the current data sample, all group sizes are 1.

Comment: No, current query **does not** work. (1) KQL is case-sensitive (2) count() does not accept parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+-----+-------------------+
| x|y | x or y (prefer x) |
+-----+-------------------+
```

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

```
let dependencies = datatable (name:string, success:bool)
[
    "api/path?id=0150403650"                          ,True   
   ,"api/path?id=0150403651"                          ,False  
   ,"another/path/0150403611/validate"                ,True   
   ,"another/path/0150403612/validate"                ,False  
   ,"more/paths/4863FDA918BB42959C88E06D72E04238/etc" ,True   
   ,"more/paths/4863FDA918BB42959C88E06D72E04238/etc" ,False 
];
let regs = dynamic([@"[\/]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}", @"[\/]+[0-9]{10}", @"[=]{1}[0-9]{10}"]);
dependencies
| extend call = replace_regex(name, array_strcat(regs, "|"), "")
| summarize c = count() by call, success
```

| call | success | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| api/path?id | true | 1 |
| api/path?id | false | 1 |
| another/path/validate | true | 1 |
| another/path/validate | false | 1 |
| more/paths/etc | true | 1 |
| more/paths/etc | false | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WSa2vCMBSGvxf6H0I%20tazS9KJrHeJ06i/w07oiMT1oIb2QpEOd/vfFus3NOWEnkMsJz/smnMNBoQxqKDMoWQ4SDVBGlR5LDsgqaQF9qURerhwkG8ZAyv6yqrhtGolpIB2Y1rlbU7Ue5tmAeF0SkqDXJRj9Gc5cNKDXlneu894tfka5hDNfVmoNotVwPwU8z32lPNdfgV9Kl/5Xef8G/9O/qAS0sHTDqBfMJqPYi8bj0I%2078VMUTUlvcu9PSegHkQuK4Uv///Mnf9NIH0yD6/oJWLV12%20py5cxKHnHy4qbDhHZ2o84z6cTpW%20AfsINOF3dJm/LIR2qg94dzLrW17PeWMI09go3SZ8Qo59pJQM0pg4U2hk3bJA6iQtDtQvcKo8o6vshBeI9tPWP7qCCboqAi3wFiWoFVTaksGy23reZXc70DzcDA748CAAA=)

Comment: That array_strcat(regs, "|") is exactly what I was looking for! And today I learned that my company calls things guids that aren't actually guids, which isn't surprising, lol. Thanks for your help. :)